# 気を使う meaning and example sentences

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation

On my online dictionary it says 気を使う also means to take into consideration. 
Does this mean be considerate ?
Iv Heard it used in a way that it would mean that but just wanted to confirm?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although 使う is generally translated as "use", a more idiomatic English translation of つかう in this case would be "pay", as in "pay attention to" or "pay mind to".

Here are a couple of example sentences from スーパー大辞林, which actually uses a different kanji for つかう in this phrase: 気を遣う.

- 彼はまわりの人に気を遣った =
  He was attentive to those around him.
- (私のことで)そんなに気を遣わないでください =
  Don't bother about me so much.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!